# Type error in Prisma query on ...WhereInput

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a simple API endpoint in Next that runs a Prisma query. I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy to production via Vercel (works fine on localhost):

```
Type error: Type '{ activated: true; }' is not assignable to type 'UserWhereInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'activated' does not exist in type 'UserWhereInput'.
```

`activated` clearly exists in my schema. How do I tell Typescript? Here's my code

```
// ../api/alert.ts

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prisma from "../../lib/prisma";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { authorization } = req.headers;

      if (authorization === `Bearer ${process.env.API_SECRET_KEY}`) {
        //make sure the service that is calling this API endpoint is authorized

        //get all users that are activated
        const activeUsers = prisma.user.findMany({
          where: { activated: true },              
        });

        // do other stuff

        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500 });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

**schema.prisma**

```
...
  model User {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid())
  phone     String
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  activated Boolean   @default(false)
  Message   Message[]
}
```

**/lib/prisma.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  let globalWithPrisma = global as typeof globalThis & {
    prisma: PrismaClient;
  };
  if (!globalWithPrisma.prisma) {
    globalWithPrisma.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = globalWithPrisma.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

Comment: When deploying, you probably need to run Prisma [generate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#generate).

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `prisma generate` to the `package.json` like so:

```
 "scripts": {
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma migrate deploy && next build"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by yourself seems to work, although I am not sure if it is a great idea to always call migrate deploy on vercel-build.

The [recommended way by Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/serverless/deploy-to-vercel) is to only use prisma generate, like so:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts" {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).